# Angular 8. Список элементов с действиями по свайпу в стороны

Tags: angular2, angular-material, gestures

Хочу реализовать функциональность жестов свайпов, как показано в материал дизайне:
https://material.io/components/lists/#behavior (прокрутите один экран вниз к разделу Gestures).

К сожалению, я новичок в Angular, и в теории может и смогу сделать что-то подобное руками, но чувствую, что это будет костыль на костыле + очень трудозатратно. Более того, сомневаюсь, что люди так редко это используют, что не найдется готовой либы. Не отрицаю возможности, что как-то не так гуглил...

На просторах интернета раскопал вот такое issue на гите, где просят добавить функционал:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4016

Дальнейшие поиски привели меня вот сюда:

https://demo.mobiscroll.com/angular/listview/swipe-actions#theme=ios
Именно то, что я искал (даже излишне), но, как я понял, это какой-то платный сервис, который выводит во все их контролы надпись DEMO через некоторое время. Я, конечно, все понимаю, но неужели не найдется такой опенсорсной библиотеки? Да и зависеть от какого-то стороннего сервиса тоже не феншуй...

[Вот еще одна библиотека](https://github.com/ShankyTiwari/ng-swipe-to-delete), которая опенсорс и визуально очень близка к тому, что я ищу, но она по свайпу удаляет из DOM элемент (что и логично так как называется swipe-to-delete), а мне необходимо повесить события на свайпы в стороны, не удаляя при этом элемент из списка.

Помогите пожалуйста, может кто-то делал что-то подобное?

**Я вижу реализацию следующей (если не найдется библиотеки):**

1. Создаем компонент, который будет представлять элемент списка.
2. Подключаем к нему DragDropModule и настраиваем, что элемент может двигаться только по оси X.
3. В TS подписываемся на события перемещения элемента и при смещении на определенный процент в ту или иную сторону, отображаем иконку действия, а при завершении движения возвращаем элемент на место и вызываем ту или иную callback функцию, которую передали в компонент при инициализации.

На счет вью компонента есть несколько мыслей:

1. Возможно смогу использовать кастомный placeholder (эту функциональность предоставляет DragDropModule). Если он достаточно гибкий - отлично.
2. Взять несколько вложенных друг в друга DIV блоков. Last Child будет движущийся элемент, а родителям вложу иконки действий, которые будут выполнятся по свайпу и задам бекграунд.

Останется только красивую анимацию возвращения элемента сделать. Далее через *ngFor набираем список элементов. 
Учитывая мой небогатый опыт, прошу вашего совета. Все ли верно, подскажите как правильно. Или подскажите либу, которая покроет нужный функционал.

**Edit:**

Так как решения не нашел - решил написать собственную реализацию. Решение еще не финальное. Еще не проверил могу ли через инпут передавать ссылки на методы (делегаты), но если нет, то сделаю соответствующий сервис. Еще не знаю как добавить анимацию, что бы после свайпа элемент плавно возвращался на место (прошу помочь с этим). В проекте использую библиотеку [material](https://material.angular.io).

**TS:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  basePosition = {x:0,y:0};

  @Input() tableId: string;
  @Input() leftSwipeMethod: any; //test
  @Input() rightSwipeMethod: any; //test


  offsetPercent: number = 0;

  private elementWidth = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  swipeStarted($event){

    console.log("Started:" ,$event)
  }
  swipeMoved($event){
    this.offsetPercent = Math.abs($event.distance.x / $event.source.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth * 2);
    console.log(this.offsetPercent)

  } 
  swipeEnded($event){
    console.log("Ended:" ,$event);
    this.offsetPercent = 0;
    this.basePosition = {x:0,y:0};
  }
}
```

**Стили**:

```
.table-container, .table-drag-box {     
     height: 50px;
}
.table-drag-box{   
     width: 99vw;  
     background-color: white;
}
.table-container{
     width: 100vw;
     background-color: red;
}
.left-icon, .right-icon{
     position: absolute;
     height: inherit;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     opacity: 0;
}
.right-icon{
     right: 0;
}
.fill-remaining-space{
     flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-container">
  <span class="left-icon" [ngStyle]="{'opacity': offsetPercent}">
    <mat-icon>credit_card</mat-icon>
    <span>Send to payment</span>
  </span>
  <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
  <span class="right-icon" [ngStyle]="{'opacity': offsetPercent}">
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
      <span>Close all sessons</span>
    </span>
     <div class="table-drag-box" cdkDragLockAxis="x" cdkDrag [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="basePosition" 
(cdkDragStarted)="swipeStarted($event)" (cdkDragMoved)="swipeMoved($event)" (cdkDragReleased)="swipeEnded($event)">
             <span> {{tableId}}</span>
         </div>     
    </div>
```

**Использование**:

```
<div *ngFor="let device of myDevicesObservable | async">

    <table [tableId]="device.id"></table>

</div>
```

Comment: В сторону Ионика не смотрели? Там есть всё что нужно для PWA. И он тоже на ангуляре.

Comment: @sneas не, пва оно и из коробки angular идет сразу, а айоник просто юзает это. У данного товарища довольно интересные и сложные вопросы, направленные на A11 :D и это не сарказм 

Comment: @overthesanity вы опять правы. Имел ввиду что ионик предоставляет нужные компоненты. А что такое А11?

Comment: @sneas ошибся в слове, "а11у" (accessibility), как i18n (интернационализация)

Comment: @sneas решение нужно довольно быстро. Нет времени разбираться с еще одним фреймворком (или надстройкой... даже не знаю, как его правильно обозвать). Я вчера довольно быстро сморганил часть решения, как и описывал выше. Когда закончу - выложу код, но буду рад, если все же найдется опытный человек, который делал подобную реализацию и поделится ей (ну или библиотекой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось куда проще, чем я думал. В процессе написания собственной реализации я углубился в Material библиотеку [Drag&Drop](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview) и понял, что легко могу использовать ее функционал. 
Для реализации нам понадобится DropList, каждому элементу которого разрешаем смещение только по оси х (cdkDragLockAxis="x"). так же устанавливаем кастомный плейсхолдер, где размещаем наши иконки. Работает именно так как я хотел! Еще не все вопросы решил с версткой, но кому нужно будет - легко сможет поправит под себя все мелочи. Надеюсь кому-то это поможет. Мне же осталось только повесить действия на свайпы и клик (см. комментарии в коде). Как установить Material описывать не буду, а покажу непосредственно реализацию (прошу прощения за именование переменных - они привязаны к моему контексту):

**HTML**:

```
<div cdkDropList class="tables-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"> <!-- метод cdkDropListDropped в моем случае не задействован, решил для вас оставить. -->
  <div class="table-drag-box" 
      *ngFor="let table of myTables$ | async"
      cdkDragLockAxis="x" cdkDrag  
      (cdkDragStarted)="swipeStarted($event)" (cdkDragMoved)="swipeMoved($event)" (cdkDragReleased)="swipeEnded($event)" (click)="showOrderDetails(table.id)">
      <div class="custom-placeholder" *cdkDragPlaceholder>
          <span class="left-icon" [ngStyle]="{'opacity': offsetDistance > 0 ? offsetPercent *4 : 0}"> <!--умножаем на 4, чтобы быстрее выводить иконку из прозрачности. -->
              <mat-icon>credit_card</mat-icon> <!--Left swipe icon-->
              <span>Send to payment</span>
            </span>
            <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span> 
            <span class="right-icon" [ngStyle]="{'opacity': offsetDistance < 0 ? offsetPercent *4 : 0}">
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon> <!--Right swipe icon-->
                <span>Close all sessons</span>
              </span>
      </div>     
    <span> {{table.id}}</span>
     </div>        
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.table-container, .table-drag-box {     
     height: 50px;
}
.table-drag-box{   
     width: 100vw;  
     background-color: white;
}

.left-icon, .right-icon{
     position: absolute;
     height: inherit;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     opacity: 0;
}
.right-icon{
     right: 0;
}
.fill-remaining-space{
     flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.cdk-drag-animating {
     transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
   }
   .tables-list.cdk-drop-list-dragging .table-drag-box:not(.cdk-drag-placeholder) {
     transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
   }
   .custom-placeholder {
     background: #ccc;
     min-height: 50px;
     transition: transform 250ms cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
   }
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CdkDragDrop } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { FullscreenOverlayContainer } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@Component({
  selector: 'tables',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tableId: string;
  @Input() myTables$: Observable<object>;

  offsetPercent: number = 0; //данное значение влияет на прозрачность иконок свайпа
  offsetDistance: number = 0; //отрицательное значение отображает правую иконку, а положительное - левую.
  constructor(private element:ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    //this.elementWidth = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;

  }

  swipeStarted($event){

    //console.log("Started:" ,$event)
  }


  swipeMoved($event){
        this.offsetDistance = $event.distance.x;
        this.offsetPercent = Math.abs($event.distance.x / this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth);  
  } 
  swipeEnded($event){
//зная % смещения можно выполнять различные действия. Вот, к примеру вот так:
    if(this.offsetPercent > 0.25){
//таймер - это костыль так как нужно дождаться окончания анимации смещения элемента. 
//Если вы знаете как подписаться на событие завершения анимации - ожидаю ваших комментариев. Заранее спасибо.
          timer(250).subscribe(_ => { 
            switch (this.offsetDistance > 0) {
          case true:
            //TODO send to payment
            this.showConfirmationDialog("Send orders on payment?")
            .subscribe(result => {  
              console.log("TODO send to payment " + result)
              return result;
            })
        break;

      case false:
        //TODO close sessions
        this.showConfirmationDialog("Close all sessions on table " + tableOrders.table.location.deviceNameForLocation)
        .subscribe(result => {              
          console.log("TODO close sessions: " + result)  
          return result;
        })

        break;
    }        
    this.offsetDistance = 0;
    this.offsetPercent = 0;
  });      
}
else{
  this.offsetDistance = 0;
  this.offsetPercent = 0;
}
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    //console.log("drop: ",event)
    //moveItemInArray(this.movies, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

  showOrderDetails(tableId){
    //TODO open full-screen dialog
    console.log(tableId);
  }
}
```